# How do I get wordpress to evaluate a shortcode inside a URL?

Tags: html, wordpress, url

I have this shortcode that shows a city name and I need it to be part of the URL of a link.

It's easy to understand what I'm trying to do just looking at the code:

```
<a href='http://chusmix.com/?s=[mmjs-city]'>[mmjs-city]</a>
```

As you see I just want the shortcode to be part of the URL, I mean add the result of the shortcode to the end of the URL. I have no idea how to do it, probably what I did doesn't make any sense. Anyway I would be really grateful for any help. Also I'm using wordpress and this code is on a page. Thanks

Comment: You need to look at your wordpress and/or theme and/or plugin documentation in order to figure out how to define and use shortcuts.

Comment: Sorry, I submitted this question about 4 months ago. I don't even remember what the problem was about. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

a simple idea if using jQuery

you should have

```
<a href="http://chusmix.com/?s=" class="underlink">[mmjs-city]</a>
```

then

```
$(".underlink").click(function(){
    document.location = $(this).attr("href") + $(this).text;
});
```

Comment: I think that should work. Just one question how do I add [mmjs-city] to the URL?

Comment: you just need to have `<a href="http://chusmix.com/?s=" class="underlink">Copenhagen</a>` and when user clicks he will jump to `http://chusmix.com/?s=Copenhagen`. If your question is to add several cities in such way, you need a scripting or programming language, as HTML is a static page. You need to generate that HTML from any scripting language such PHP, ASP, Javascript or Programming language, Java, .NET, etc... what you can do if you don't want to mess with languages, if to fetch a list using javascript, that list can be a single page or a file (text, xml, or web service)

Comment: It does't work I believe it's because I'm in a page and not in the theme. I think I can't run java in pages and neither PHP. Maybe I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on your infrastructure:

**If you use a dynamic backend (recommended)**

To do this, make use of your backend.  Use php, jsp, anything to iterate over your cities and generate a link for each of them, with the value filled in (make sure to url-escape the short codes though).

**If you have a static backend, but are creating a dynamic site using JavaScript**

Call some kind of service using Ajax to retrieve your cities.  Then generate tags that have the correct url and content.  I don't recommend the suggestion given here to use the onclick event to go to the url, it will break browser functionality, such as 'open in a new tab'.

**If you're using static backend and static html**

Nothing to do about it, it'll be copy-paste action for you :)